# Plot of likelihood Function for the Uniform Density. $ (\theta-1,\theta+1)$

Tags: likelihood

Let the random variables $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$  iid $U[\theta-1\,,\theta+1]$. 
So the likelihood function is

$L(\theta|X)=\prod_{i=1}^nf(X_i|\theta)=\frac{1}{2^n}I(X_1, . . . , X_n \in [\theta-1\,,\theta+1])$

but I have no idea how draws the likelihood curve. hint please

Comment: start with a sample - say three observations like (4.28, 3.47, 2.61). Can you evaluate the likelihood at say $\theta=3.4$? If so, then choose a grid of $\theta$-values (say 2, 2.2, 2.4, ..., 4.4)  and actually compute the likelihood at each. Then figure out how it's changing between those grid-points. You'll soon get the hang of how to do it in general, and much more quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: which among the $X_i$ are most important to the indicator function? Draw a series of intervals if you're unsure.

Comment: the most important are the $x_1=min(x_i) $ and $x_n=max(x_i) $ ?

Comment: Yes. And what's the likelihood between them?

Comment: I have no clear